# Shuffle List with fixed Random does not return the same result

Tags: java, collections

I have a method that at some point shuffles a `List`. It is important that I can reproduce this shuffle later. To achieve this I pass a `Random` to the method that then gets passed to `Collection.shuffle(List, Random)`. I expected that using the same Random with the same list would result in the same shuffled list but apparently I'm missing something.

Example code with `String`s instead of my objects:

```
    @Test
    public final void shuffleTest() {
        Random random = new Random(555);

        List<String> text = new ArrayList<>();
        text.add("one");
        text.add("two");
        text.add("three");
        text.add("four");

        List<String> shuffled = shuffleList(new ArrayList<>(text), random);
        List<String> shuffled2 = shuffleList(new ArrayList<>(text), random);
        Assertions.assertThat(shuffled).isEqualTo(shuffled2);
    }

    private List<String> shuffleList(List<String> text, Random random) {
        Collections.shuffle(text, random);
        return text;
    }
```

I did notice that if instead of passing the `Random`, I pass the seed and do `new Random(seed)` every time it does work, but I would like to avoid that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have supplied the answer yourself.  After initialising a `Random` instance, it will produce a sequence of pseudo-random numbers.  Some of this sequence will be consumed by the first shuffle, and so the second shuffle will use the next bit of the sequence.  In order to use the same sequence the `Random` instance must be in the same state before each of the shuffles.  A new instance with the same seed fits the bill.

Answer (score 7):

If you did this:

```
List<String> shuffled = shuffleList(new ArrayList<>(text), new Random(555));
List<String> shuffled2 = shuffleList(new ArrayList<>(text), new Random(555));
```

They would indeed be equal.

However, you are using the same random instance twice: after the first shuffle, the `Random` is in a different state than it was beforehand, so it will shuffle the list differently.

Answer (score 3):

The first call to `Collections.shuffle(text, random);` will "use up" some of the random numbers in the `Random` instance that you pass in.  The shuffled lists will  only be the same if the first bunch of random numbers are the same as the second bunch, and the way you are using `Random`, that would only happen if the first `n` numbers of `Random(555)` repeated themselves.

If you want the two lists to be sorted with the same set of random numbers, you have to give them a `Random` with the same seed, and with the same amount of its random numbers consumed (in this case, 0).

e.g.:

```
Random random = new Random(555);
List<String> shuffled = shuffleList(new ArrayList<>(text), random);
random = new Random(555);
List<String> shuffled2 = shuffleList(new ArrayList<>(text), random);
...
```